# Interactively show/hide code R Markdown/Knitr report

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a way to show/hide code interactively in a R Markdown/Knitr report?

Comment: Please give a minimal example script, the commands of how you are processing it, and a fuller description of how the user reads and interacts. There's lots of ways of doing Markdown/knitr that it helps to know precisely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could do that at least by using the HTML output, like in this minimal example:

````
---
title: "Toggle Code boxes"
output: html_document
date: "January 12, 2016"
---

First add the javascript to toggle boxes(remember to indent it)

  <script language="javascript"> 
    function toggle(num) {
      var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText" + num);
      var text = document.getElementById("displayText" + num);
      if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
      }
      else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
      }
   } 
  </script>

and then we have some R code with the toggle button wrapped around (also indented):

  <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle(1);">Show underlying code</a>
  <div id="toggleText1" style="display: none">

```{r}
x <- sample(100)
mean.x <- mean(x)
```

  </div>

The mean is `r mean.x`. Please click the link to see the source code.

  <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle(2);">Show underlying code</a>
  <div id="toggleText2" style="display: none">

```{r}
median.x <- median(x)
```

  </div>

And the median is `r median.x`. Please click the link to see the source code.
````

Comment: What if I always want to see a printed output and show/hide the code?

Comment: I am not sure if this would be the most efficient solution, but as workaround, I'd recommend then two separate chunks, in the code chunk you calculate the results and then you store them there. And the result chunk just prints them then, the latter one you keep then always visible and the first one you just toggle.